# How to upload images on my React app from firebase storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to make a social media app. I wanted to add a feature of uploading pictures but I don't know how to fetch those pictures in my firebase storage and display all of them as a post on my app.

This is my firebase.js file

```
    import firebase from "firebase/app";
    import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCbiHH-zpob5AytooHMxrB_oncIz5wAcgg",
    authDomain: "expresate-react.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://expresate-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "expresate-react",
    storageBucket: "expresate-react.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "400618187775",
    appId: "1:400618187775:web:d78270044e4b1d464215ca"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = firebase.storage();

export { storage, firebase as default };
```

This is the function which uploads the image on the firebase storage.

```
const image = this.state.selectedFile;

    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {},
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            storage
            .ref("images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              this.setState({url: url, selectedFile: null});
            });
        }
    );
```

The upload feature is working perfectly I can see the files in firebase storage. Now, how do I fetch them and display them on my app?

Thank you

Comment: everything is right but don't disclose your API key to the public your project can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already get the `url` with `getDownloadURL`.
It is an url like [this](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/react-most-wanted-3b1b2.appspot.com/o/users%2FtrdWsbwQCGTxOSemSe3i6s27m5D2%2F23f93734-6f28-4286-b42e-269681f76dcb.jpeg?alt=media&token=59a6a778-a706-48f2-a75c-1717d5e75e98) one.

You can use that to display your image. Just put that url into a `img` like here:

```js
<img src={url} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but I want to get those urls everytime I launch my website like in a social media website.

Comment: Can you pls explain a little bit more what you want. I realy don't get it.